# How to design GUI properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and I don't understand how do I configure the resolution of the font, I wanted to design it but it keeps on expanding, because of the grid(?), Thanks in advance

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
selection=('Weight','Volume','Length')
length = ('mm', 'cm', 'inches','feet', 'yards', 'meter', 'km', 'miles')
weight=('mg','lb','g','kg','oz','ton')
volume=('ml','l','gal','pt','qt')

#title
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Conversion APP")
window.configure(background='#a1dbcd')
title=tkinter.Label(window,text='Welcome to the Converter APP!', fg="#383a39", bg="#a1dbcd", font=("Helvetica",16))
title.grid(row=0,column=2)
title.config(width=100)
window.geometry("300x200")
#1st
labelOne = ttk.Label(window,text='Enter Value',background='blue')
labelOne.grid(row=1,column=0)
to_be_converted = ttk.Combobox(values=length, width=10)
to_be_converted.grid(row=1, column=2)

#2nd
labelTwo = ttk.Label(window, text="Convert To",background='blue')
labelTwo.grid(row=2,column=0)
converted = ttk.Combobox(values=length, width=10)
converted.grid(row=2, column=2)

#input
userName = tkinter.DoubleVar()
userEntry = ttk.Entry(window, width=5, textvariable = userName)
userEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

#button to convert
btn = ttk.Button(window, text='Convert!', command=convert_length or convert_weight or convert_volume)
btn.grid(row=1, column=4)
#button to exit
exit= ttk.Button(window, text='Quit', command=exit_converter)
exit.grid(row=2, column=4)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is `command=convert_length or convert_weight or convert_volume` meant for? You cannot do this. There is a way to access multiple functions at once but this is not it. That said you reference what is a function I am assuming in your buttons but do not have those functions in your code. This will cause errors.

Comment: If you do not want the grid to resize then you will need to use `container_name.grid_propagate(False)` to stop the grid from resizing.